# Struggling to create an uneven grid in Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, grid-layout, gridbaglayout

I have a working application that uses [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html) to make a 2 by 2 grid, each containing a [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JPanel.html).

The `GridLayout` worked just fine, I just did `mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2))`, and everything worked out just fine.

However, I noticed that 2 of my components were a little cramped (horizontally) inside of the grid. I know that I could swap my layout to using [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/CardLayout.html) or something instead, but the application I am building is more of a dashboard, and therefore, having all the elements viewable at once is rather important. And this lack of horizontal space is for a maximized window, so maximizing isn't an option.

Well, as it turns out, the other 2 components had horizontal space to spare, so I thought to myself, "Why don't I just move the 2 big components into the same column, the 2 small components into the other column, and then resize the column so that they both have the adequate space they need?"

Here is a simple visual representation of what I mean.

[image: Image of 2 grids, demonstrating the current state on the left side, and my desired state on the right side. Left side is an evenly sized grid. Right side is a grid where the left column is much wider than the right column.]

As it turns out, `GridLayout` (understandably) does not provide this functionality, so I decided to cycle through the different Swing layouts listed [in this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Of all the layouts, [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) seemed to be the best fit for my needs.

So, I took a look at the [tutorial for `GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). My first goal was to recreate what I already have with `GridLayout`, then manipulate that solution until it looks like what I needed.

Here is my first, naive attempt. This was after skimming through the tutorial.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class GUI
{

    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public GUI()
    {

        this.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        this.frame.add(createPanel());

        this.frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private static JPanel createPanel()
    {

        final JPanel grid = new JPanel();
        grid.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.MAGENTA));

        final java.util.function.Supplier<JPanel> createButtonGrid =
         () ->
         {

            final JPanel buttonGrid = new JPanel(new java.awt.GridLayout(4, 4));

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {

               buttonGrid
                  .add
                  (
                     new
                        JButton
                        (
                           """
                           <html>
                           THIS IS BUTTON TEXT<br>
                           THIS IS BUTTON TEXT<br>
                           THIS IS BUTTON TEXT<br>
                           THIS IS BUTTON TEXT
                           </html>
                           """
                        )
                  );

            }

            return buttonGrid;

         };

        TOP_LEFT:
        {

            final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;

            final JPanel tempPanel = createButtonGrid.get();
            tempPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
            grid.add(tempPanel, c);

        }


        TOP_RIGHT:
        {

            final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 0;

            final JPanel tempPanel = createButtonGrid.get();
            tempPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE));
            grid.add(tempPanel, c);

        }

        BOTTOM_LEFT:
        {

            final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;

            final JPanel tempPanel = createButtonGrid.get();
            tempPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
            grid.add(tempPanel, c);

        }

        BOTTOM_RIGHT:
        {

            final GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;

            final JPanel tempPanel = createButtonGrid.get();
            tempPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
            grid.add(tempPanel, c);

        }

        return grid;

    }

}
```

When I run this, already things are a bit different than expected. The components are all scrunched in the middle.

`GridLayout` ensures that each component takes up all available vertical and horizontal space. I need this if I am going to be using `GridBagLayout`. After all, the entire reason why I just switched over to `GridBagLayout` was to be able to squeeze out just a little more horizontal width. What I have now is a step backwards.

So, I read through the tutorial again, thoroughly this time, and saw the following quote.

> fill
>
> Used when the component's display area is larger than the component's requested size to determine whether and how to resize the component. Valid values (defined as GridBagConstraints constants) include NONE (the default), HORIZONTAL (make the component wide enough to fill its display area horizontally, but do not change its height), VERTICAL (make the component tall enough to fill its display area vertically, but do not change its width), and **BOTH (make the component fill its display area entirely)**.

Reading that, I tried to add a `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;` for each of the components. However, the result was 100% the same. No difference between the first version and the second version.

Reading through a second time, I noticed the following quote.

> A GridBagLayout places components in a grid of rows and columns, allowing specified components to span multiple rows or columns. Not all rows necessarily have the same height. Similarly, not all columns necessarily have the same width. Essentially, GridBagLayout places components in rectangles (cells) in a grid, and **then uses the components' preferred sizes to determine how big the cells should be**.

Reading that, I started trying out different preferred sizes. That had an impact, but not quite what I wanted. Now my GUI doesn't resize correctly. The preferredSize that I provide is what the component stays at. I need my components to take up all horizontal space. If my display area increases or decreases in size, I need my components to follow suit while maintaining proportion to each other.

So, I tried to reread the tutorial again and found the following quote.

> For example, to make button 4 be extra tall, the example has this code:
>
> c.ipady = 40;

So, I tried ipadx, but it didn't change anything. It looked the same as my first 2 attempts.

Finally, I tried to reread the tutorial again, but nothing else seemed like it would work for my solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No idea what the Supplier class is and why you feel you need to use it to create an MRE. I guess its another new feature you feel you you need to use before even learning the basics of Swing as in your last question. In any case I can't test the code. *The components are all scrunched in the middle.* - GridBagLayout respects the preferred size of components. By default all components will then be centered in the space available. Components can only grow when the `weightx/y` constraint is used.  This will allow the GridBagLayout to allocate extra space (when available) to those components.

Comment: The `fill` constraint is not used to determine the width/height of a cell. It is only applied after the fact. For example the width of a column is determined by the width of the largest component in the column. By using this constraint you can force a smaller component to take the same width as the largest component. Since all your cells are the same size this has no effect.

Comment: *I started trying out different preferred sizes.* - don't play with preferred sizes. Each component should determine its own preferred size. The layout manager will then set the size based on the rules of the layout manager.

Comment: @camickr In regards to Supplier, I added the import. It's a core part of the Java Standard Library since Java 8.

Comment: @camickr As for the weights, I see what you mean. Gilbert Le Blanc showed me what that looks like, and I got to see first hand how the lack of extra space will keep things scrunched in the middle.

Comment: @camickr That fill point is very helpful, ty. I read the tutorial multiple times, and I see now that I misunderstood what they mean by display area.

Comment: *As for the weights,* - yes, but that was a poor answer since it only provided a core dump of the code without explaining what was changed to make the code work.

Comment: @camickr Fair enough about the preferred sizes. I guess the part that my brain tripped up on was that, when I saw weight, my brain immediately jumped to ratios. The tutorial says as much. But the confusion was that, I thought the ***component sizes*** would follow the ratio. In reality, it's the ***amount of whitespace given*** that follows that ratio. I observed similar behaviour on my own, but got confused when the weight seemed to make the components grow on a curve instead of linearly. I now see why that was happening.

Comment: *I thought the component sizes would follow the ratio. In reality, it's the amount of whitespace given that follows that ratio.* - correct. If you really want ratios then check out [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). I have all the code on GitHub now.

Comment: @camickr Beautiful, ty vm. And thanks for using GitHub. Grabbing the code no longer throws weird http warnings in my browser. I think I will actually end up using your RelativeLayout. That follows my mental model way more intuitively. Using weights ***for whitespace*** means that you will *eventually* converge to the ratio that you want, but the ratio *you currently have* will be slightly different for each monitor. The behaviour is similar to limits from high school calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your GUI to get the following.

[image]

The components expand when you expand the window.

[image]

Generally, when creating a Java Swing GUI, you start by picking out the Swing components you want to use, like `JTextFields`, `JLabels`, and `JButtons`.  You place these components in one or more `JPanels`.  You place one or more `JPanels` in your `JFrame`.

You have to take into account the size of the monitors that will display your Swing GUI.  Some monitors may be too small to display everything.  In Windows, you have to take display scaling into account as well.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Each individual `JPanel` uses a `GridBagLayout`.  The main `JPanel` uses a `GridBagLayout`.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutTest5 implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridBagLayoutTest5());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(createButtonPanel(Color.BLUE,
                "This is really long button text"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        panel.add(createButtonPanel(Color.RED, "This is button text"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        panel.add(createButtonPanel(Color.BLUE,
                "This is really long button text"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        panel.add(createButtonPanel(Color.RED, "This is button text"), gbc);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel(Color color, String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color, 5));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;

        for (int index = 0; index < 16; index++) {
            gbc.gridx = index % 4;
            gbc.gridy = index / 4;
            panel.add(createTextButton(text), gbc);
        }

        return panel;
    }

    private JButton createTextButton(String text) {
        String s = "<html>" + text + "<br>" + text + "<br>";
        s += text + "<br>" + text + "<br></html>";
        JButton button = new JButton(s);
        return button;
    }

}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and when I ran it, the resulting GUI had all components being evenly sized. Maybe this has to do with monitor sizes? Mine is 1366x768. Yours seems to be much larger.

Comment: Also, for SwingUtilities, I think you meant to make the constructor call as a lambda? EDIT - oh nevermind, I see that you implemented Runnable.

Comment: Interesting, so I swapped out your long button text for something shorter, and your short button text for something even shorter, and it worked. So I see that your solution does work, but it's inconsistent for different monitor sizes.

Comment: @davidalayachew: The code you posted had `JButtons` with the same text I used, so I assumed your monitor was that large.  See my updated answer for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for doing this. Yes, you are correct, the text was the same size, and it helped me realize what my problem was, as well as discussing with camickr. Apparently, weights only apply when there is extra whitespace. Otherwise, the components are evenly sized. And even if there is extra whitespace, only the whitespace is distributed by proportion. The components themselves don't just jump to that ratio -- they slowly ease themselves to that ratio depending on how much whitespace there is. On large monitors, the ratio is shown. But on mine, they might just stay as equal sized components.

Comment: @davidalayachew: True.  The example GUI is all `JButtons`, so they will be equal in size on smaller monitors.  A mixture of `JLabels`, `JTextFields`, and `JButtons` will react differently on smaller monitors.  That's why you have to design your GUI to fit the monitor sizes you have.  Sometimes, you put additional information on `JDialogs`.

Comment: That's a good point. I am experimenting with another Layout. If that doesn't work, I might just do as you said.

Comment: Thanks to the help of you and @camickr, I actually did manage to get things working with the GridBagLayout after all. Thanks again to you both! Coming back to this several hours with a fresh head, I realized that even though the weight only applies to the whitespace, it is very much a good enough solution for my purposes.